# Startup delay in ffmpeg recording of UDP stream

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming

I'm recording an RTP stream using FFMPEG with the following command:

`ffmpeg -i udp://127.0.0.1:1234 -t 00:00:30 -vcodec prores -profile:v 3 output.mov`

The Problem being that at the start of the video there are some seconds of delay at the start of the resulting file. It shows the first frame of the following video but it stays for about 3-7 seconds. An ideal solution would be the use of Unix pipes since it would reduce the delay until the final file is available but using temporary files should work as well.

In case it does help somehow, this is the command used for creating the stream:
[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/YUMYjZRE)

(It delays an incoming RTP stream by 30 seconds and then retransmits that for later capture of 15s before and 15s after a specific point in time)

EDIT: If there's a better solution than using a UDP stream to attach to the output of the delaying process at any time that would be even better of a solution since there'll be about thirteen of these workflows running in parallel.

Comment: I believe your input starts mid-GOP hence the freeze. Use the trim filter to chop off the first few seconds.

Comment: I thought about that as well but the problem is that timing is rather crucial so the start time of the recording should be as close to starting ffmpeg as possible. But thanks for the hint on the GOP I'll try lowering the interval on the source (since it's @ the same device bandwidth doesn't really matter)

Comment: To identify if that's the issue in one go, reduce GOP to 1 i.e. `-g 1`

Comment: I restructured it a bit by writing the original stream to a file and then reading from the end of that file into a new file while the first file is still being written (that actually works, which I didn't expect) which solved my problem but `-g 1`  definitely improved the startup lag (used it later in the chain).